# What is the total revenue generated by all the trips? The fare is stored in the column total_amount

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

[image]

where last column total_amount is of decimal(9,6) type from where we need to find out the revenue.

I tried

1. select sum(total_amount) from taxidata;
   (#taxidata is table & total_amount is column)
   which gives answer as 'NULL'
2. select sum(total_amount) from taxidata group by vendor_id;
   Answer: 1 NULL
   4 NULL
   2 NULL
3. I also tried select sum(total_amount decimal (9,6)) from taxidata;
   but failed.

Comment: Are you showing all the data in your table? Please use text, not images. Is there a row with "null" in total_amount?

Comment: Please see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056). Then kindly edit your Question. Note that stating you tried something but failed is very vague. How did it fail? (Your attempt nr. 3)

Comment: if the data like in your picture, your first and second query should produce not null results. Is it oversimplified example or something else, nobody knows, only you. Try to prepare minimal reproducible example including table DDL, load data and select query.

Comment: You should check if the total_amount has a "null" value with the "CASE" keyword. If so change that null value to 0

Comment: @NevilleKuyt sorry about the image , there are more than 100M rows in the file.  I will see is there any null value in total_amount which is last column.

Comment: @Scratte Fail , means it says there should not be  word 'decimal (9,6)' in that bracket.

Comment: Kindly edit your Question to include all necessary information to answer your Question. Do not provide those in comments.